# How to mention the Excel attachment under a form

Tags: academic-writing

I'm filling out a form and section A of the form refers to the content of the Excel attachment . (The Excel attachment and the form are combined together as PDF, they are one document)

Is this correct if saying "please refer to the attachment below " or "please refer to the attached spreadsheet". Which one sounds better ?